# How to handle wesocket connections on load balanced servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, websocket, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer

Our .net core web app currently accepts websocket connections and pushes out data to clients on certain events (edit, delete, create of some of our entities).

We would like to load balance this application now but foresee a problem in how we handle the socket connections. Basically, if I understand correctly, only the node that handles a specific event will push data out to its clients and none of the clients connected to the other nodes will get the update.

What is a generally accepted way of handling this problem? The best way I can think of is to also send that same event to all nodes in a cluster so that they can also update their clients. Is this possible? How would I know about the other nodes in the cluster?

The will be hosted in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distribute the event to all nodes in the cluster, so that they can each push the update out to their websocket clients. A common way to do this on AWS is to use SNS to distribute the event to all nodes. You could also use ElastiCache Redis Pub/Sub for this.

Comment: I'm assuming I need to use a combination of SNS and SQS here? SNS sending out events via HTTPS would hit load balancer again. How would I direct it to a specific node that will not be accessible from the web?

Comment: I was thinking more like you would have each server subscribe to the SNS topic using it's direct DNS name, so that the SNS notifications wouldn't hit the load balancer but go directly to the server. ElastiCache Redis Pub/Sub is probably a cleaner implementation since all the connections are outgoing from the servers and you wouldn't have to manage SNS subscriptions.

Comment: I ended up going with ElastiCache Redis Pub/Sub as you suggested. Was just way simpler and cleaner for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to SNS or Redis, you could use a [Kinesis Stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction.html). But before going to that link, read about [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/), because the AWS docs don't do a good job of explaining why you'd use Kinesis for anything other than log ingest.

To summarize: Kinesis is a "persistent transaction log": everything that you write to it is stored for some amount of time (by default a day, but you can pay for up to 7 days) and is readable by any number of consumers.

In your use case, each worker process would start reading at the then-current end-of stream, and continue reading (and distributing events) until shut down.

The main issue that I have with Kinesis is that there's no "long poll" mechanism like there is with SQS. A given read request may or may not return data. What it does tell you is whether you're currently at the end of the stream; if not, you have to keep reading until you are. And, of course, Amazon will throttle you if you read too fast. As a result, your code tends to have sleeps.