# Create SQS queue when scaling out and delete when scaling in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to get the nodes of my autoscaling group to respond to events through SNS and SQS.

This is the original question:
[How to handle wesocket connections on load balanced servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913829/how-to-handle-wesocket-connections-on-load-balanced-servers)

The solution I'm thinking of is one SNS topic that would receive all events like "EntitySaved". Each node in the scaling group would then create an SQS queue and subscribe it to the SNS topic.

I'm not sure how to reliably handle creating and deleting these queues as the scaling group scales in and out. Any ideas? What would be the simplest solution here?

I could obviously create a queue and listen to it when the application starts up, but there is no reliable way to delete it once the auto scaler decides to scale in?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, new to all this.

Comment: "What would be the simplest solution here?"

Don't use SNS/SQS. In the answer that you were given, Redis pub/sub was suggested as an alternative.

Comment: I'm also writing an answer to your other question, suggesting Kinesis as a solution.

Comment: Do Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Elasticache Redis pub/sub as suggested in the comments above and in initial question. It does exactly what I need in a way simpler way than the other options.